# Show that $1+ab+a^{2}b^{2}+\cdots=\frac{xy}{x+y-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here is a question I am currently struggling with -

> If $$x=1+a+a^{2}+\cdots$$ where $\vert{a}\vert \lt 1,\;$ and
>   $$y=1+b+b^{2}+\cdots$$ where $\vert{b}\vert \lt 1,\;$ then
>   show that $$1+ab+a^{2}b^{2}+\cdots=\frac{xy}{x+y-1}$$

What I know is that you can get $xy$ by multiplying $x=1+a+a^{2}+\cdots$ and $y=1+b+b^{2}+\cdots.$ I'm clueless as to how $x+y-1$ can be derived.

I have spent almost an hour on this and still can't work it out.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your progress into the body of your question?

Comment: @Martund - Can it be in words?

Comment: Absolutely, but sometimes scratchwork takes less time to write and needs less explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

You may just use the geometric series

- $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}q^n = \frac1{1-q}$ for $|q|<1$

So, you have $x=\frac 1{1-a}$ and $y= \frac 1{1-b}$ and to show is

$$\frac{xy}{x+y-1} = \frac{1}{1-ab}$$

Now, plug in the expressions for $x$ and $y$ into the left-hand side and simplify.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've understood it now. +1

Comment: @Justin You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

$x$ and $y$ just represent convergent geometric series. In general, for $|r|<1$ we have:

$$1 + r + r^2 +\cdots= \frac{1}{1 - r}$$

Hence, $x = \frac{1}{1 - a}$, which implies $a = 1 - \frac{1}{x}$ and similarly for $y, b$. Then:

$$1 + ab + (ab)^2 +\cdots = \frac{1}{1 - ab}$$

Substituting the corresponding equations for $a, b$ in terms of $x, y$ into the RHS will give you the identity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Completely missed the fact that $x$ and $y$ represent convergent geometric series. +1